# Review of Name Entity Recognition NLTK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am trying to create one entity recognition(NER) application, where I am trying to take Parts of Speech Tagging(PoS) approach.
I am trying to exploit Python's NLTK library, and using it as `hmm_tagger=nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(train_set)`.
In train set, I am trying to give data in the format of Brown corpus's tagged_sents(). 
It is as below for PoS Tagging

```
brown_a = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[:2]
>>> brown_a
[[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'County', u'NN-TL'), (u'Grand', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Jury', u'NN-TL'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'Friday', u'NR'), (u'an', u'AT'), (u'investigation', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u"Atlanta's", u'NP$'), (u'recent', u'JJ'), (u'primary', u'NN'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'produced', u'VBD'), (u'``', u'``'), (u'no', u'AT'), (u'evidence', u'NN'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'any', u'DTI'), (u'irregularities', u'NNS'), (u'took', u'VBD'), (u'place', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')], [(u'The', u'AT'), (u'jury', u'NN'), (u'further', u'RBR'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'term-end', u'NN'), (u'presentments', u'NNS'), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'City', u'NN-TL'), (u'Executive', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Committee', u'NN-TL'), (u',', u','), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'had', u'HVD'), (u'over-all', u'JJ'), (u'charge', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u',', u','), (u'``', u'``'), (u'deserves', u'VBZ'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'praise', u'NN'), (u'and', u'CC'), (u'thanks', u'NNS'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'City', u'NN-TL'), (u'of', u'IN-TL'), (u'Atlanta', u'NP-TL'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'for', u'IN'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'manner', u'NN'), (u'in', u'IN'), (u'which', u'WDT'), (u'the', u'AT'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'was', u'BEDZ'), (u'conducted', u'VBN'), (u'.', u'.')]]
```

{Here size of brown_a we may increase. It is given only as an example.}

I am now trying to build an NER, where, I am changing above data as,

```
[[(u'The', u'NameP'), (u'Fulton', u'Name'), (u'County', u'NameC'), (u'Grand', u'NameCC'), (u'Jury', u'NameCCC'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'Friday', u'NR'), (u'an', u'AT'), (u'investigation', u'NA'), (u'of', u'NA'), (u"Atlanta's", u'Name'), (u'recent', u'NA'), (u'primary', u'NA'), (u'election', u'NA'), (u'produced', u'NA'), (u'``', u'NA'), (u'no', u'NA'), (u'evidence', u'NA'), (u"''", u"NA"), (u'that', u'NA'), ...]
```

Here, I am keeping data format but changing the tagset to my definition as, NA for Not Available(anything which is not NE),
                                                                            NameP for Previous to Name,
                                                                            Name for Name,..etc.

I am now making this new data as training set and training.

Is my approach fine or do I need to change anything major?

Please suggest.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. However, you may need to use POS and chunk tags as features while training and tagging. This may not be possible with simple emission-based HMM.

Comment: FWIW, I'd use CoreNLP for production systems if that's what this is.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use a ready NER system, such as [CRF-NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) or [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/)?
Are you doing this for academic purposes or you have a business problem, which needs to be solved? In case of the latter, try working with something already built to get the initial results and if they don't meet your expectation, only then consider your implementation.

Comment: Result is okay but as it is an expert place before carrying forward I am trying to review how I am going.